# boost::function and plain function pointers: ambigous overload

Tags: function-pointers, overloading, functor, boost-function

Given the following member function overload to take various functors

```
class Foo { 
public: 
     void bar(boost::function<void(int)> func); 
     void bar(boost::function<void(float)> func); 
     void bar(boost::function<void(const std::vector<float>&)> func); 
}
```

and the function

```
void baz(float f) { std::cout << "float :" << f << std::endl; }
```

then why does taking the plain function pointer of baz

```
Foo foo; 
foo.bar(&baz);
```

yield this error:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘bar(void (*)(float))’ is ambiguous 
note: candidates are: void Foo::bar(boost::function<void(int)>) 
note: void Foo::bar(boost::function<void(float)>) 
note: void Foo::bar(boost::function<void(const std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >&)>)
```

How to resolve this ambiguity ?

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty and not safe:

```
foo.bar( static_cast<function<void(float)> >( &baz ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative: use [Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wd1177.aspx).

```
foo.bar( function<void(float)>{ &baz } );
```